# dynamic editext and textview plus slqlite update syntax

Tags: android, sqlite, swipe

hi i have a mobile program using android studio , i have here an edittext and a textview which is dynamically created and the number of edittext and textview is base on the sqlite column **Quantity** and **Unit** . and ill also add a printscreen on the the exact out put [image: here is the pic] and what i want is that when i swipe the fragment the value in edittext will save in sqlite and update the depends on the **UNIT** which is the textview that is dynamically created. i have done swiping and sqlite query update and i just dont know the logic on how to save the edittext depends on the textview values which is both edittext and textview is dnamically created and looped inside cursor query

//here is the code in creating dynamic textview and edittext using cursor which is it is inside a fragment

```
public static class PageFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String id = "id";
        public static final String cate = "category";
        public static final String code = "code";
        public static final String desk = "description";
        public static final String unit = "unit";
        public static final String quan = "Quantity";
        TextView tv;
        EditText et;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, container, false);


            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.item_label2)).setText(
                    getArguments().getString(cate));
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.item_label3)).setText(
                    getArguments().getString(code));
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.item_label4)).setText(
                    getArguments().getString(desk));
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.item_label5)).setText(
                    getArguments().getString(unit));
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.item_label6)).setText(
                    getArguments().getString(quan));
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.item_label1)).setText(
                    getArguments().getString(id));

            TextView code = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.item_label3);
            DBController controller = new DBController(getActivity());
            SQLiteDatabase db2 = controller.getWritableDatabase();

            Cursor mCursor2 = db2.rawQuery("SELECT Unit,Quantity FROM Countsheet WHERE TRIM(Code) = '"+ code.getText().toString() +"'", null);

            while (mCursor2.moveToNext()) {
                LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);
                // add text view
                            List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
                            data.add(mCursor2.getString(0));
                     for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                         tv = new TextView(getActivity());
                         tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 18);
                         tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                         tv.setText(data.get(i));
                         tv.setId(R.id.unit);
                         ll.addView(tv);

                         et = new EditText(getActivity());
                         et.setHint("Input Quantity");
                         et.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                         et.setId(R.id.quanity);
                         et.setText(mCursor2.getString(1));
                         et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                         ll.addView(et);
                     }

//                mArrayList.add(mCursor2.getString(mCursor2.getColumnIndex(DBController.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.Col_5)));
//                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            return rootView;

        }
```

//here is my code in update query

```
public void updateContact(data data) {

        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.Col_6, data.get_Quantity());
        // updating row
        database.update(TABLE_NAME, values, ""+FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.Col_3 + "='" + data._Code+ "' AND "  +  FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.Col_5 + "='" + data._Unit + "'", null);
        data.set_Code(data._Code);
        data.set_Unit(data._Unit);
        database.close();
    }
```

//here is my code in swipe to update which is in another fragment

```
public class PagerFragment extends Fragment {
    private List<PageData> data;
    private int currentPosition;
    private View v;
    EditText q;
    TextView unit;
    TextView code;


    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager, container, false);
         mViewPager = (ViewPager)v.findViewById(R.id.pager_view);
        currentPosition = getArguments().getInt("CURRENT_POSITION");
        data = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("DATA_LIST");
        final FragmentItemPagerAdapter fragmentItemPagerAdapter = new FragmentItemPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), data);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(fragmentItemPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPosition);
        onswipe();
        return v;


    }
    private void onswipe(){
        final DBController controller = new DBController(getActivity());
        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                unit = ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.unit));
                String units = unit.getText().toString();
                code =  ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_label3));
                String codes =  code.getText().toString();
                q = ((EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.quanity));
                String quan = q.getText().toString();
                data data = new data();
                data.set_Code(codes);
                data.set_Unit(units);
                data.set_Quantity(quan);
                controller.updateContact(data);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"" + codes + quan + units,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

    }

}
```